# Printing to either STDERR or {*STDERR}?

Tags: perl

I have seen both variants:

```
say STDERR    'hello world';

say {*STDERR} 'hello world';
```

Any difference? Security considerations, best-practice, ...?

Comment: One word to the "quick-downvoters": Short and on the first sight simple questions can get interesting if you take the time to really understand all the background. See my comment to the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that the first variant is the idiomatic way to express it and I don't think I have ever seen the second variant for simple file handles.

The second variant is a simple example of a more general construct where you can decide the filehandle dynamically. For example it could be useful to write code something like:

```
say { $errors_on_stderr ? *STDERR : *STDOUT } "hello world";
```

Where the variable is used to decide which file handle should be used. You can use any perl expression inside the curly brackets. Another example would be if you have the filehandle stored in a hash. Then it can be necessary to write

```
my $data = { fh => *STDOUT };
say { $data->{fh} } "Hello world";
```

But in your simple case I would for the first variant.

Comment: Thanks @pmakholm for sharing your point of view and the examples. Finally I found the reason for having seen both variants when I run `$ perlcritic -1 script.pl`. Using the **braced variant** is considered a best-practice but only because it visually distinguishes the file-handle from the other arguments. This PBP is defined [here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic-1.116/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/InputOutput/RequireBracedFileHandleWithPrint.pm)

Comment: Now you mentions it I recognise it as something PBP would recommend – Not that I agree and Perl::Critic seems to have it at the lowest severity.

Comment: The reason it's recommended is for lexical filehandles: `print {$output}, "some text";` is a syntax error, where `print $output, "some text";` isn't, but doesn't do what you wanted. (In addition to the clarity point). Neither of which IMO really apply to `STDOUT`/`STDERR`.